# Object attributes in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

Lets say i have a python class like:

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, name=""):
        self.name = name
    def print_attr(self):
        return vars(self)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and RF script like:

```
*** Settings ***
Variables         mine.py
*** Test Cases ***
Example
${DOG}=    Set Variable    ${MyObject("dog")}
${CAT}=    Set Variable    ${MyObject("cat")}
${MyObject.does_it_fly}=    Set Variable    nope
${CAT.does_it_fly}=    Set Variable    yeeep
```

When I `Log    ${DOG.print_attr()}` and `Log    ${CAT.print_attr()}` I get the results, respectively:

```
{'name':'dog'}
{'does_it_fly':'yeeep', 'name':'cat'}
```

But when I `Log    ${DOG.does_it_fly}` I get the `nope`.

My question is, why the "does_it_fly" attribute does not show in "DOG" object attributes, but when I'm checking it individually, it appears?

Is there a way to show all the class attributes? What I'm I doing/assuming wrong?

I tried to check the class attributes with the __dict__, dir, vars (example below) but the result is the same - only "name" is shown. (I guess it's because the function is checking what is written in the .py file physically):

```
def class_attr():
    return MyObject().__dict__
```

EDIT:
Actually, `dir(self)` instead of `vars(self)` does print all the attributes of `DOG` object, but it also includes methods.

Comment: i dont know what is a RF but Python has also `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`, as well as properties, so no problem to have attributes which are not real attributes. May be this is the reason ?

Comment: @Paul-AG `getattr(DOG, 'does_it_fly')` works basically the same as calling `DOG.does_it_fly`. It will not list all of the `DOG` object attributes. Unless there is an extra functionality which I'm not aware of.

Comment: Are you sure this line `${MyObject.does_it_fly}=    Set Variable    nope` shouldn't be `${DOG.does_it_fly}=    Set Variable    nope`? Presently you're not changing the object instance assigned to DOG through the class it instantiated from. That's not going to work.